# have another public void inside a first

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write an app w/ AIDE using the android java, the end result I need is a app that uses a slider that when I release the slider, the number associated with the position of the slider to the IP "insert IP here" and the port "insert port here", but I'm pulling the values from a different class, and I need it to write to the values inside of the method, how do I pull the variable out of the method?

```
public void sendPort(int port){ 
    //TO-DO take port variable and input into sendIp
}
```

inside of

```
public void sendIp(String ip){
    //needs the port variable in here
}
```

but when I try, it tells me I have errors in my code and can't compile until the errors have have been fixed, the errors I get say that there is a "Missing '}'" and after that a "Unexpected '}'". Is there something like a public void or a method to getting the curly bracket detected is the script?
code for the menu

```
public void showChangeLangDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        final EditText ip = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        final EditText edt = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit2);

        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Custom dialog");
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("Enter text below");
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    String port = edt.getText().toString();
                    mTcpClient.sendIp(String.valueOf(ip));
                    mTcpClient.sendPort(Integer.valueOf(port));
                    //do something with edt.getText().toString();
                }
            });
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    //pass
                }
            });
        AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
        b.show();
    }
```

code to retrieve the variables and send the slider position number

```
public void sendMessage(String message){
        if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
            out.println(message);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
    }
    public void sendPort(int port){
        Log.i("TCPClient", "Recieved Port");
        int SERVERPORT = 0 + port;

        public void sendIp(String ip){
            Log.i("TCPClient", "Recieved IP");
            String SERVERIP = "" + ip; 

        try {

            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            try {
//send the message to the server
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");
                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");
//receive the message which the server sends back
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
//in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                while (mRun) {
                    serverMessage = in.readLine();
                    if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
//call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                    }
                    serverMessage = null;
                }
                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
            } finally {
//the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
// after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                socket.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);
        }
    }

//Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
//class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }
    }
```

I'm grabbing the values for port and IP from a menu in a different class and the second script you see is a class that is not an activity it is just a background class.

Comment: Why would you *need* to put a method inside another method (which you can't do in Java)? Why do you believe you *need* to do that?

Comment: You want to declare the `sendPort` method inside of `sendIp` method? Or call `sendPort` inside `sendIp` ?

Comment: You could make an anonymous function inside of the other function, but you can't nest public/private/protected methods inside of eachother

Comment: Also is your problem more about the android side or the java method side or things?

Comment: I have tried to put my code in but i gave up because it said i had a formatting error is my script, I'll try to fix the error and put my script in

Comment: I need to retrieve the "port" variable from the method or somehow nest the method inside the sendIp method

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you can't declare a new method inside of another method. If you need two separate methods, declare them separately in your class, then call one inside the other like this:

```
public void sendPort(int port){ 
    //some sort of code here
} 

public void sendIp(String ip){
    //some code 
    sendPort(portAsInt);
    //more code
}
```

If you don't need two different methods, then just include the logic that would be in the `sendPort` method in the `sendIp` method.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is pull the values from a settings text dialog box from another activity.